# Can a low-rep user see their own deleted questions/answers?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, visibility

Let's say there is a user who has 1 rep.  That user asks a question/gives an answer, and I can see its going in the trashcan.  I then add a comment to it before it gets deleted.

I'm wondering if

1. the user will be notified that they have a comment (their cute little envelope is yellow) and
2. the user will be able to view their own deleted post.

Comment: If they can be bothered coming back that is.

Comment: @won't Yellow envelopes, what is this o.0  [google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Stackexchange+yellow+envelope&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=cloVVPC4HI_oaM3ZgugG&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1920&bih=995) wasn't very helpful.  Nevermind, finally found it [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/822/where-is-the-yellow-envelope)

Comment: @PopeyGilbert look at the date.  Always look at the date.  [Related.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98589/automatic-visual-indication-of-old-questions)

Comment: @won't Ah, very sorry.  Won't happen again =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Juan succinctly addresses point 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57687/can-a-low-rep-user-see-their-own-deleted-questions-answers/57688#57688)

Below the line is the original answer, which used to be how things behave. Now, it appears that proper comment replies are *not* retained in your envelope post-deletion. So when a post is deleted, your envelope no longer reports any comment activity.

However, there is an excerpt in the global inbox, which will give the user a link to the post. But, as mentioned by Juan, they can only see deleted answers so it will be useful only for answers.

---

For comments, if it is just a plain comment on their content, then no, they do not get any alert or message. I just checked back on an old deleted answer of mine, and checked my envelope's report, it completely skips all of the comments that were addressed to me on that answer.

However, if it is a comment reply with @name, then it overrides this problem and will be retained (though be decidedly awkward in some cases as you will only have the ones that actually mention your name). It will even work if it was someone else's content that was deleted.

Here is what this post looks like, with color coding the comments.

[image: Blue is none, red is has]

And this is what my report looks like, note the absence of comments in the timespan.

[image: Only the red one]

Comment: Want to try it again here? You're the first sub-10k to answer.

Comment: @mmyers I just tested it at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/56448/are-typo-notices-appropriate-for-meta/56450#56450. If I delete the answer, then I can only see Popular's comments that actually have @Grace, not any of the ones that don't. However, if you add an @Grace comment, I could get some free hand circles going.

Comment: Ok, give me a second.

Comment: @Grace: Undeleting in two minutes...

Comment: I guess you could have deleted it yourself, but I wanted to duplicate the conditions as closely as possible.

Comment: This is a complex version of my answer...

Comment: Yes yes, I was only kidding, I need to remember to add smileys

Comment: Or one of those fancy signature unicode characters like your ♪

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes
2) Answers yes, questions no