# Does a comment with @user notify user's StackExchange Inbox?

Tags: support, comments, global-inbox

Often times I will post an answer to a question only to have the OP comment on *my* answer saying "this is nice, but I really need it to do X, Y and Z as well."  I'll then update the answer to accommodate this new request but now I'm curious how I can notify the OP that my code has been updated without posting a comment under *his* question.  I've noticed several comments with the `@user` idiom and I'm wondering if that is merely for readability sake or if it actually has some functionality behind it.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Comment: @SiegeX: Check your inbox.

Comment: Thank you all. The link provided by Jon only mentioned the envelope, but now I see it actually dumps it into the inbox. My envelope didn't do anything but I read there may be some lag associated with that.

Comment: @Bill: that was unnecessary, the poster will be notified of *any* comment which is made on *their own* post (or on all posted answers in case of a question). Comment replies is only useful whenever you want to reply on a comment on a post which is not commenter's own.

Comment: @BalusC: Now you should receive a useless message in you StackExchange inbox. LOL

Comment: @Linuxmint: and also in SiegeX's inbox.

Comment: @BalusC: Yup! It worked!

Comment: @BalusC: That's right.  I'm in the habit of always using @user comments now, so I keep forgetting.

Comment: My inbox is blowing up, I feel so special!

Comment: I think there was some theoretical reason to use @username even if it's on username's own post; this came up before. Maybe it's just in case the system ever decides to show directed comments differently

Comment: @Michael It used to allow [comment replies on deleted posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57687/can-a-low-rep-user-see-their-own-deleted-questions-answers/57689#57689). However, that has ceased to be the case, so using it in reference to the post author is more of a formality these days.

Comment: I added the global inbox to [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) As there are quite some rules, I vote to close this as a duplicate, to ensure future readers get to know those rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, putting *@user* will show up in the users "Stack Exchange" inbox.

But: **only** for the first `@user` (and always for the original author of the question/answer one is commenting on). See all nifty details in [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: @Arjan: Nice editing! :D