# Should some questions be retired?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, old-questions

In the computer/software world technologies advance fast.
Some questions that where answered in 2008/9 are no longer relevant, or will be none relevant in the future.
But SO still keeps them and Google will still fetch them as a high ranking result.
Should there be a mechanizem to retire or some how archive no longer relevant questions/answers?

Comment: How about some specific examples?

Comment: similar:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98589/automatic-visual-indication-of-old-questions

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple of problems with retiring old questions.

1. They are too localized.  The problem is, moderators do not get involved in judging content; i.e. a flag indicating "This answer is wrong" is not actionable.  It's not the role of moderators to judge posts by accuracy of technical content or timeliness.
2. There still might be the off chance that some people are maintaining an old technology, so answers like this are still potentially useful to someone.

Comment: The issue, and I am sorry I do not remember of the top of my head the exact example, it was not in my account, My team needed to ask some question which had an old duplicate with irrelevant answers for us (I believe it was answered with IE 6 in mind). But, our question was closed for being an exact duplicate.

Comment: Well, I'm probably in the minority, but I don't generally close a question as a dup if the original is very old, or has crappy answers.

Comment: Sadly, you are :-)

Comment: @ItayMoav: if that's the case, I believe you should comment to that effect and/or edit your question to explain that that previous question does not apply to version X.Y.Z of the framework/language/library you are using. I'm pretty sure a mod and/or 10k users would reopen the question if that is indeed the case.

Comment: @Mat - but how will they know it is there among the hundred of questions opened each day? Is there a flag option for this case?

Comment: You can flag it (use the "Other..." reason and explain your case clearly but succinctly), or you could ask about it here (with a link to the question obviously) (that's been done a few times), or, if there is commenting activity on it, you might not need to do anything - if the question is good, it does happen that it gets sufficient views to get re-opened "organically". But the question has to be _good_.