# Indication of when an ancient question has been bumped

Tags: feature-request, old-questions

I've done it a lot; leave a comment, an edit, or maybe even start writing an answer on a post I saw on the front page.

Then I notice the post dates are from 2010; an ancient question someone edited or posted an answer to. It would be nice if after a few months or so a little icon or indication showed up on old posts on the "active" page.

MS Paint mockup go:
[image]

The icon could have a `title` attribute, so when you hover your mouse it says something like:

> Originally asked May 2010

It could save us some accidental necromancy, or even be a good indicator in Unanswered Questions/ect for an opportunity to get the Necromancery/Revival badges. It would also give an indication of when someone's been answering or editing a very old post, which reeks of intentional bumping or late answers.

Comment: The 10k tools even have a "New Answers to Questions More Than 30 Days Old" page. So, a more publicly visible indicator (like the one suggested by Ben above) would also be nice to allow *everyone* to help detect smelly new posts to old questions!

Comment: I was more hoping to prevent *additional* smelly new posts after someone has bumped an old question. By showing that's it's old we could discourage (unnecessary) new answers or comments. When I see a post on "active" that I haven't seen before I always assume it's brand new, I'm sure that's the default assumption in general. Old posts are special and should be marked as such.

Comment: True, Ben, and I like the idea. (Surely it has happened to me before too!) Just trying to give even more reasons to add such indicator. ;-)

Comment: As a sidenote, Community often bumps ancient posts on Meta sites that are effectively "resolved" but don't have a literal accepted answer. I almost commented on one of those just now :)

Comment: The view count is excellent indicator - usually more than 100 means old question bumped for editing/retagging and 4K is obviously ancient. But adding some neat icon is still good idea, count me in. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard popular posts (especially the ones in the Hot Questions box) occasionally do get a couple thousand views in a brief time. This one: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/14880/how-could-one-prevent-drunk-users-from-using-a-mobile-application got 3 K views in like 3-4 days.

Comment: related  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98589/automatic-visual-indication-of-old-questions

Comment: @Ben true, but pretty rare IMO :)

Comment: @ಠ_ಠWon't The accepted answer there is due to the scanning vs reading argument; I don't think that applies, I know a text-based indication would be ignored and cluttersome but that's not what I'm suggesting. An icon is a quick cue for power users, the `title` is a quick way to learn for curious users, and it fades into the background otherwise. (you know you're really hard to reply to)

Comment: (I wasn't trying to close as dupe, I was agreeing that this is a good suggestion and trying to repwhore....er, pimp my solution)