# Historical notice locked posts should look different

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, historical-lock

Posts with a historical lock notice look almost like ordinary posts. All that distinguishes them is:

- The absence of voting arrows, a minor detail, especially to people who are not habitual Stack Exchange users.
- The absence of the `edit` or `improve this question` link.
- A discrete notice under the question that indicates that “it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site”. This notice often blends in with the protection and closure notice. It's well-known that users don't read, and we're not even making it easy for them to find this important piece of information.

Historically noticed posts  should be indicated far more prominently.

- Put the lock notice at the top. That way, it won't blend in with the other notices, and it won't be lost below a potentially long question text.
- **Use the deleted question style.**

This is in effect what had been proposed by Jeremy Banks in [Add the alternative of "delisting" questions; deletion is usually harmful overkill](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116419/add-the-alternative-of-delisting-questions-deletion-is-usually-harmful-overki)) and Pekka  in [Show embattled deleted questions to the public as if they were 10k+ users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124464/show-embattled-deleted-questions-to-the-public-as-if-they-were-10k-users). As things stand now, the historically noticed posts are pretty much displayed as ordinary posts; we might as well not bother.

Comment: Hmmm, if this gets done I'd say use a different colour (say green) as the background - to reflect the fact they are not deleted, but archived.

Comment: A faded parchment background would be cool... in particular with the historical context ;)

Comment: @Oded: [why, that's such a good idea it should be applied to all old questions!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98589/automatic-visual-indication-of-old-questions)

Comment: @Won't - Genius! Great minds and all that :)

Comment: We have plans for this...but the current state certainly isn't a bug.

Comment: @Gilles - you can disagree with the design, sure, but that's still not a bug.

Comment: @NickCraver Sure, the implementation conforms to the technical specification. The problem is that the technical specification does not conform to the concrete requirements.

Comment: @Gilles - *Who's* requirements? Yours? That's a **feature request**, literally, by definition.  We have larger plans for archiving questions, and won't waste time here on an interim solution...it would be *totally* wasted effort.

Comment: @NickCraver Ok, this requirement wasn't spelled out in the blog post. But the lock notice reads “… it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site …”; I took it as a requirement that this lock notice should be visible to people with no SE experience.

Answer (score 1):

If these posts are being kept around in part because of off-site users (which would explain why they're delisted from searches), having them displayed with the deleted color-scheme would be wrong.

I'm not saying that they shouldn't have a *different* color-scheme. But the deleted one is very... harsh. It's off-putting, and looks really unpleasant on the site. It also makes the text harder to read.

Remember: these off-site links could be the first that a user sees of Stack Overflow. We should try to make a good impression, even with questions that are not in keeping with the site's current best practices. It's good information (that's why we're not deleting it, after all); we shouldn't make it look like non-information. And we shouldn't suggest that all of SO looks like that.

A shiny heading would probably be the best way to go for this. A special header, possibly with a *slight* background shift to a off-white grey.

Comment: Looking off-putting is the point.

Comment: @Gilles: Your point, perhaps, but not mine. They should look different, to show that they're not the standard fare. But they shouldn't look off-putting. Remember: this may be the first view of Stack Overflow for some people. They need to see something attractive.