# On-hold questions should have on-hold music

Tags: feature-request, fun, on-hold

Since a [closed question is now listed as "on hold" for the first five days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154), I think the page should play [hold music](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hold_music) (autostart on load). This feature would supply the following advantages:

- It would make even clearer to the asker that the question is on hold.
- It would be an immediate indication to others that the question is on hold rather than closed, without their having to see the post notice or title (which of course is very hard to do).
- It would be soothing music to calm the asker's nerves, in case they're frazzled from his question's being on hold.

Comment: "*soothing music to calm the asker's nerves"*...either that or it will drive them insane, resulting in a killing spree.

Comment: Yes, and I suggest we use "[Closing Time](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGytDsqkQY8)" by "Semisonic"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something fun. And we hate fun. 

Comment: It's not off-topic. It's a feature request.

Comment: +1 the world needs more `bgsound`

Comment: And we should be able to upvote/downvote the chosen music.

Comment: I recommend Pantera's [(Fricking) Hostile](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E929gqIcwwI) (Link possibly NSFW) Also; it's not Friday where you are!!

Comment: +1 because this is a great it, -1 because I couldn't imagine having to listen to onhold music for 5 days.  I got annoyed with it after 5 minutes last time I called my cable company

Comment: Sorry, had to close this because the custom close reason was way to awesome

Comment: @HugoDozois Dammit, I had hoped for it to appear below...

Comment: We              hate       fun.

Comment: @George totally wrong close reason, fun or no fun.

Comment: somewhat related: [Automatic visual indication of old questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98589/165773) and [New background for deleted posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211478/165773)

Comment: @gnat first one not really (and no [tag:fun] tag there) second is indeed related. Nice find!

Answer (score 8):

Whenever unexpected music starts playing on a browser page, I find it annoying.  I think it would cause some anxiety for anyone on a page with an on-hold question, especially in an environment such as a job or a computer lab with others present.  This would cause the browser page to be immediately closed by the user, and it would drive those people from the site.

I think that "[on hold]" plus the new reason(s) is sufficient for notifying someone that the question is on hold.

I think that this request should be rejected because it would reduce site participation.

Comment: -1 for not playing along. +1 for a good answer, anyway ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber [joke] Perhaps there should be a "joke" tag.

Comment: @rgettman There is. It is [always-friday-in-iceland](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/always-friday-in-iceland)

Comment: @rgettman we have the [meta-tag:fun] :-)

Comment: I guess it was time to brush up on the [Always Friday in Iceland Meme](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/21413#21413).