# Custom OT closure wording not working

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, close-reasons, off-topic

When [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186330) had but three close votes, I clicked "close" to see the reasons offered, and all three were for "This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something fun. And we hate fun.". The fifth voter's comment on the question indicates that he chose the same reason, so there was no alternate reason chosen by ≥two voters. Yet the question got closed with default wording.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is partially [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), but something is not quite right.

According to [Closing changes: on hold, unclear, too broad, opinion-based, off-topic reasons, bye-bye to Too Localized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons) where the new changes were announced,:

> Closers can enter a free-form reason ("Your question appears to be about 'Cat Grooming', which is off-topic for Stack Overflow.")
>   Free-form reasons will be presented as comments, but the close dialogue will refer the reader to the comments for more info

However, the closed banner does not direct the user to the comments.